# How to hide/remove "Request New password" link in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, users, blocks

I am using 'Login Block' to access Intranet pages from our website. I used 'Login Block' on www.example.com/common-intra
 page to login into intranet section.

I am using [userprotect](https://www.drupal.org/project/userprotect) module to hide profile/username/password information from the users when they logged in into Intranet section (www.example.com/common-intra) with universal account.

But, I wanted to hide/remove "Request New password" link from Intranet Login page:

I found this module, haven't used yet though:[image]
https://www.drupal.org/project/noreqnewpass

Is there any other easy way to just hide **"Request New password"** link from that Intranet Login page?

I still want this tab on general login page such as:
www.example.com/user
 But, I just want to hide it from the www.example.com/common-intra page.

I also tried to hide it with css.

This is my page source code:

```
<div class="panel-separator"></div><div class="panel-pane pane-block pane-user-login common-intra pane-user common_login_button"   class="panel-pane pane-block pane-user-login common-intra pane-user common_login_button">


    <div class="pane-content">
        <form action="/common-login?destination=node/16" method="post" id="user-login-form" accept-charset="UTF-8"><div><div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-name">

      <label for="edit-name">Username <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>

     <input type="text" id="edit-name" name="name" value="" size="15" maxlength="60" class="form-text required" />
    </div>


<div class="form-item form-type-password form-item-pass">
  <label for="edit-pass">Password <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>

 <input type="password" id="edit-pass" name="pass" size="15" maxlength="128" class="form-text required" />
</div>


    <div class="item-list">
<ul>
<li class="first last"><a href="/user/password" title="Request new password via e-mail.">Request new password</a></li>
</ul></div>

<input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="form-_xyzabc" />
```

```
<div class="form-actions form-wrapper" id="edit-actions"><input type="submit" id="edit-submit" name="op" value="Log in" class="form-submit" /></div></div></form>  </div>

  </div>
```

I gave class name `'common-intra'` to user login block to my node template.

```
.common-intra ul li{
    display: none;
}
```

I also tried:

```
.panel-pane pane-block pane-user-login common-intra pane-user common_login_button ul li
    {
          display: none;
    }
```

Comment: finally, you got some advance?

Answer (score 4):

this will remove it from the render array before it is printed. In your theme's template.php, add:

```
function MYTHEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
    if($form_id == 'user_login_block')
    {
        $form['links']['#markup'] = '<div class="item-list"><ul><li class="first"><a href="/dev/user/register" title="Create a new user account.">Create new account</a></li></ul></div>';
    }
}
```

Basically, it is just rewriting the markup for the links in the user login block. You can tweak this to theme as well. this should only apply to the user block

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [No request new password](https://www.drupal.org/project/noreqnewpass) module:

> Remove "Request new password" link from block and user page.

I tested the module and it works fine.

Another solution is to put this in your page.tpl.php just before the render($tabs) line this code. Works fine on Drupal 7 :

```
<?php
if(isset($tabs['#primary'][2]['#link']['path']) && $tabs['#primary'][2]['#link']['path'] == 'user/password'){
   hide($tabs['#primary'][2]);
}
?>
```

You can find other solutions in:

> [Disabling 'Request new password' on Login block](https://www.drupal.org/node/244720)
>
> [How to remove menu tabs front login page?](https://www.drupal.org/node/194536)

Comment: Thanks. 
'noreqnewpass' module is nice but it removes "request new password" link from all page even on www.example.com/user page too.
I just want to remove "request new password" link from particular one page which is www.example.com/common-intra

Comment: @Vidushi try the code in my answer in your intranet.tpl page

Answer (score 1):

As per [API reference](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7.x), in your custom module you can:

`function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
   // Example - disable the page at node/add
   $items['user/password']['access callback'] = FALSE;
}`

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7.x